# Implement toggle-based page rotation rxjs Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

For a project I have a simple container which contains a number of cards. Since there are a lot of cards, there are multiple pages and when the screen is displayed it automatically rotates to the next page every X seconds **OR** when the user hits the space bar.

For a new feature we have added a toggle button to turn the automatic rotation off. I have created an `EventEmitter` for the `toggle-button` as can be seen below in `toggleEmitter` but I am quite new to rxjs and not sure how to use it to actually stop the rotation. Anyone can help?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'rotator-container',
  templateUrl: './rotator-container.component.html',
})
export class RotatorContainerComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ContentChildren(RotatorItemComponent, { read: ElementRef })
  rotatorItems: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  @Input() rotationInterval = 30 * 1000;

  @Output() toggleEmitter: EventEmitter<MatSlideToggleChange> =
    new EventEmitter();
  toggle(event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    this.toggleEmitter.emit(event);
  }

  timer$ = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
    map(params => params['rotate']),
    switchMap(rotate =>
      rotate === 'false' ? of(0) : timer(0, this.rotationInterval)
    )
  );

  spaceCounter$ = fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(document, 'keydown').pipe(
    filter(({ code }) => code === 'Space'),
    tap(e => e.preventDefault()),
    map(() => 1),
    scan((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0),
    startWith(0)
  );

  rotationCounter$ = combineLatest([this.timer$, this.spaceCounter$]).pipe(
    map(([index, offset]) => index + offset)
  );

  rotatorSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const rotatorItemsLength$ = this.rotatorItems.changes.pipe(
      map(() => this.rotatorItems.length),
      startWith(this.rotatorItems.length)
    );

    const visibleIndex$ = combineLatest([
      this.rotationCounter$,
      rotatorItemsLength$,
    ]).pipe(
      map(([index, length]) => index % length),
      startWith(0)
    );

    this.rotatorSubscription = visibleIndex$.subscribe(visibleIndex =>
      this.rotatorItems.forEach((item, index) => {
        (<HTMLElement>item.nativeElement).style.visibility =
          visibleIndex === index ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        (<HTMLElement>item.nativeElement).style.position =
          visibleIndex === index ? 'relative' : 'absolute';
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.rotatorSubscription && this.rotatorSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you recreate something in a stackblitz? I would suggest that you should probably use a `BehaviorSubject` to hold the toggle state and then use this in your streams. I just tried to write an answer but I think it would be helpful if you had a minimal reproduction I could play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need an EventEmitter. Rather you need to change the way the `timer$` Observable works.

What I would try is the following.

First of all define a `Subject` which will emit `true` or `false` any time the toggle button state is changed. In particular it emits `true` if the toggle button is on, `false` otherwise.

This piece of code would look like this

```
  // use a BehaviorSubject to specify a value which gets emitted at the start, in this case false
  toggleSubject = new BehaviourSubject<bool>(false)
  ....
  toggle(event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    this.toggleSubject.next(event.checked);
  }
```

Then change the `timer$` Observable. One way of proceeding could be the following.

```
// first we just rename the current timer$ to _timer$
_timer$ = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
  map(params => params['rotate']),
  switchMap(rotate =>
    rotate === 'false' ? of(0) : timer(0, this.rotationInterval)
  )
);

// then we redefine timer$ stream starting from toggleSubject
timer$ = toggleSubject.pipe(
  // any time toggleSubject emits we switch to a new stream
  switchMap(toggleVal => {
    // if toggleButton is on then the automatic rotation is off otherwise is on
    // this is accomplished by returning an Observable that emits 0 in the first case
    // or the old definition of timer$ in the second case
    return toggleVal ? of(0) : this._timer$
    
  })
)
```

Comment: Thankss, this is exactly what I needed!